# Manipulating XML values through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

The following is the XML where the `<Validation>` tag can have 1....n of `<Failed>` tags.

```
<Header>
    ...
    ...
</Header>
 <Validation>
    <Type>Classic</Type> 
    <Percentage>10</sPercentage> 
     <Failed>
          <ID>CS-20192018</ID> 
          <Department>MF404</Department> 
          <ErrorDescription>Failed at server</ErrorDescription> 
     </Failed>
     <Failed>
          <ID>CS-3233333</ID> 
          <Department>MF404</Department> 
          <ErrorDescription>Failed at webservice</ErrorDescription> 
     </Failed>
  </Validation>
 <Validation>
      <Type>CheckMember</Type> 
      <Percentage>20</Percentage> 
      <Failed>
          <ID>CS-4648902</ID> 
          <Department>MF404</Department> 
          <ErrorDescription>Data not available</ErrorDescription> 
      </Failed>
  </Validation>
```

**Requirement**:

I just wanted to summing up the percentage based on the `<Failed>` count.

First `<Validation>` tag:

```
Percentage * no of <Failed> count = Result1
10 * 2 = 20
```

Second `<Validation>` tag:

```
Percentage * no of <Failed> count = Result2
20 * 1 = 20

Total = Result1 + Result2 = 20 + 20 = 40
```

Hence, I want to get total percentage output as 40 and I tried with `xsl:call-template` approach but it went up in smoke.

Could you please share me the code snippet to calculate the percentage sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. There are different possible XSLT 1.0 solutions**:

.1. Non-recursive, using the `xxx:node-set()` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">

 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfResults">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(ext:node-set($vrtfResults)/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="Validation">
  <x><xsl:value-of select="Percentage * count(Failed)"/></x>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (corrected to be made well-formed):**

```
<t>
    <Header>
    ...
    ...
    </Header>
    <Validation>
        <Type>Classic</Type>
        <Percentage>10</Percentage>
        <Failed>
            <ID>CS-20192018</ID>
            <Department>MF404</Department>
            <ErrorDescription>Failed at server</ErrorDescription>
        </Failed>
        <Failed>
            <ID>CS-3233333</ID>
            <Department>MF404</Department>
            <ErrorDescription>Failed at webservice</ErrorDescription>
        </Failed>
    </Validation>
    <Validation>
        <Type>CheckMember</Type>
        <Percentage>20</Percentage>
        <Failed>
            <ID>CS-4648902</ID>
            <Department>MF404</Department>
            <ErrorDescription>Data not available</ErrorDescription>
        </Failed>
    </Validation>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
40
```

.2. Using primitive recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Validation[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Validation[following-sibling::Validation]">
     <xsl:param name="pSum" select="0"/>
     
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Validation[1]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pSum" select="$pSum +Percentage*count(Failed)"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Validation">
     <xsl:param name="pSum" select="0"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pSum +Percentage*count(Failed)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
40
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 (XPath 2.0) solution**

**The following can be also specified as a single XPath 2.0 expression that doesn't need XSLT at all**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:sequence select="sum(Validation/(Percentage*count(Failed)))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**also produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
40
```